# How to set my android app as a Lock Screen?

Tags: android

I want to develop my custom Android Lock Screen. So that if I install that app in any phone, it replace the default lock screen. Any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with the help of [this project](http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/).
This project will help anyone trying to develop similar app.

Comment: Just check out the [Adenda SDK](http://adendamedia.com). You can be up and running in minutes